# How to hide the modal by tapping the background in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

After clicking a button, the modal shows or hides by changing the value of "show"

```
@State var show = false
```

**but how can I hide the modal view  by tapping the background when the modal shows just like the case of Instagram**

[image]

I solve the problem by adding two onTapGesture, one on the modal view, the other on the VStack, if you have some better solution, please inform me, thanks.

```
VStack{
            Spacer()
            Reserve(selected: self.$seleted,show: self.$show)
                .offset(y:
                self.show ?
                    (UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)!+15
                    : UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            )
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("xxx")
            }
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.label.withAlphaComponent(self.show ? 0.2 : 0)))
        .onTapGesture {
                self.show = false
        }
```

Comment: I have added my solution which is not that elegant to my post, and if you have some better way, please tell me, thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample implementation. I hope it will help you.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private  var show = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.show.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Show sheet")
            }
            if show {
                CustomSheet(show: $show)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct CustomSheet: View {
    @Binding var show: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Color.red.frame(height: 300)
        }.background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5).onTapGesture {
            self.show.toggle()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, but this didn't solve my problem because it resulting in toggle the state of the modal by taping  everywhere, what I want is just taping the background behind the modal to hide it.